# Unit tests using StructurMap ObjectFactory fails

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, structuremap, rhino-mocks

I have a class that I want to write unit tests for. I'm using StructureMap (2.6.3) in the project and I have some problems with that.

For testing I use Nunit (2.6.0.12054) and RhinoMocks (3.6).

Normally i inject my dependencies in the constructor of my classes and then it's easy to substitute the dependencies with mocks in my unit tests. But there are a few cases where I can't do that, where I have no control over when the class under test is created. In these cases I use ObjectFactory.GetInstance() to get the dependencies.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int MyMethod(string parameter)
    {
        var myDependency = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IMyDependency>();
        try
        {
            return myDependency.CalculateValue(parameter);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Suppress exception.
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

For this class and method I want to write two tests. First I want to to test that the dependency is called and the value it calculates is returned by the class under test. Second, the dependency might throw an exception and I want to test that this exception is suppressed by the class under test and that it return zero in that case.

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyClassTests()
{
    [Test]
    public void MyMethod_DependencyReturnsValue_ReturnsValueFromDependency
    {
        //Arrange.
        const int valueFromDependencyStub = 333;
        var myDependencyStub = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IMyDependency>();
        myDependencyStub.Stub(x => x.CalculateValue()).Return(valueFromDependencyStub);
        ObjectFactory.Inject<IMyDependency>(myDependencyStub);
        var target = new MyClass();

        //Act.
        var result = target.MyMethod("test");

        //Assert.
        Assert.AreEqual(valueFromDependencyStub, result);
    }

    [Test]
    public void MyMethod_DependencyThrowsException_ReturnsZero
    {
        //Arrange.
        var myDependencyStub = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IMyDependency>();
        myDependencyStub.Stub(x => x.CalculateValue()).Throw(new Exception());
        ObjectFactory.Inject<IMyDependency>(myDependencyStub);
        var target = new MyClass();

        //Act.
        var result = target.MyMethod("test");

        //Assert.
        Assert.AreEqual(0, result);
    }
}
```

Both these tests work if I run them individually, but if I run the both it does not work. I my real case the second test, where the stubbed dependency throws an exception, runs first. When the other test runs the stubbed dependency still throws an exception.

The problem, as I understand it, is that I'm using the global ObjectFactory and inject my stub into that. That would probably work if I could clear the ObjectFactory after each test, but I found no way to do that. ObjectFactory.EjectAllInstancesOf() sounded like something that would work, but it doesn't.

How do I solve this? Either by changing my test or by actually rewriting the class under test.

Comment: Sounds like this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274527/reset-objectfactory-in-structuremap

Comment: Nope, tried that but it doesn't help. :( The first stub I inject into ObjectFactory is still there and it is used.

Comment: @haagel that really *should* work. Could you try putting `ObjectFactory.EjectAllInstancesOf<IMyDependency>()` at the end of those unit test methods?